# Multiple Query Params with Asyncronous Call Retrofit

Tags: asynchronous, retrofit

UPDATE:

I have learned what I am looking to do is to use the Async within Retrofit with multiple queries too.  I have updated my code, but I cannot get the async with the queries.

I am using Retrofit to make my data calls to a movie database and need to change the sort order depending on user settings.  I am not clear how I could add this functionality to my interface.

sort_by=highest_rating.desc

or

sort_by=popularity.desc

Interface:

```
public interface MovieDatabaseApiCient {
@GET("/3/discover/movie")
void getData(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("sort_by") String sortByValue, Callback<MovieDbModel> response);
```

}

UPDATED API INTERFACE:

```
public interface MovieDatabaseApiCient {
@GET("/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=xxxxxxx")
    void getMoviesByPopularityDesc(Callback<MovieDbModel> response);

@GET("/3/discover/movie?sort_by=vote_average_desc&api_key=xxxxxxxx")
void getMoviesByVotingDesc(Callback<MovieDbModel> response);
```

}

UPDATED DATA CALL THAT WORKS:

```
private void makeDataCall(String sortPreference) {
    final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ENDPOINT_URL).build();

    MovieDatabaseApiCient apiLocation = restadapter.create(MovieDatabaseApiCient.class);

    if (sortPreference.equals(this.getString(R.string.sort_order_popularity)) ){
        apiLocation.getMoviesByPopularityDesc (new Callback<MovieDbModel>() {

            @Override
            public void success(MovieDbModel movieModels, Response response) {
                movieDbResultsList = movieModels.getResults();
                MoviesGridViewAdapter adapter = new MoviesGridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.movie_gridview_item, movieDbResultsList);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d("ERROR", error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    } else {
        apiLocation.getMoviesByVotingDesc(  new Callback<MovieDbModel>() {

            @Override
            public void success(MovieDbModel movieModels, Response response) {
                movieDbResultsList = movieModels.getResults();
                MoviesGridViewAdapter adapter = new MoviesGridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.movie_gridview_item, movieDbResultsList);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d("ERROR", error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

My call for the data:

```
private void makeDataCall (String apiKey, String sortPreference) {
    final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ENDPOINT_URL).build();

    MovieDatabaseApiCient apiLocation = restadapter.create(MovieDatabaseApiCient.class);

    apiLocation.getData(apiKey, sortPreference, new Callback<MovieDbModel>){

        @Override
        public void success(MovieDbModel movieModels, Response response) {
            movieDbResultsList = movieModels.getResults();
            MoviesGridViewAdapter adapter = new MoviesGridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.movie_gridview_item, movieDbResultsList);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("ERROR", error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I found a way to do Synchronously, but not asynchronously.

Comment: Your code is async already

Comment: I realize it is Async, but it does not compile.  I get code error beginning with the onsuccess and failure blocks.  It doesn't know the parameter moviemodels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and comment, IHMO, you should `import retrofit.Callback;` instead of `import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;`

My code as the following has no compile error:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // creating a RestAdapter using the custom client
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_URL_BASE)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(mOkHttpClient))
                .build();

        WebService webService = restAdapter.create(WebService.class);

        retrofit.Callback<GetRoleData> callback = new Callback<GetRoleData>() {
            @Override
            public void success(GetRoleData getRoleData, retrofit.client.Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        };

        webService.getData("api_key", "sort_by", callback);
    }
```

Interface:

```
public interface WebService {
    @GET("/3/discover/movie")
    void getData(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("sort_by") String sortByValue, Callback<GetRoleData> response);
}
```

So, please check your code again

Comment: I do import retrofit.Callback. I should have mentioned I am using Retrofit 1.9 and it appears you are using 2.0.  I have no OkHttpClient class available.  My current solution is not ideal (I don't think) with the repeat of code needed to call 2 separate methods within my api.  I will try your way with 2.0 for I like the lesser code.  Thanks!

Comment: I have tried with 2.0 beta and then cannot use RestAdapter.  When I use 1.9 I cannot use OkHttpClient.  I am not sure what you are using, but I cannot get your solution to work.  What am I overlooking?  Thanks for all your input!

Comment: My code uses retrofit 1.9 too (you can see I use RestAdapter). About OkHttpClient, you can complie okhttp lib inside build.gradle file.

Comment: My build.gradle: `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
}`